# Sum date using awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to add up days in a date using awk this way:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print date -d $(date -d "20181222" "+%Y%m%d") + 30}'
```

But my return is

```
030
```

I was expecting

```
20190121
```

The date I have is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is interesting to describe why you get the result you get.

In awk, an unquoted word (that is not a function or command) is a variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print date -d $(date -d "20181222" "+%Y%m%d") + 30}'
```

Here, you have the "date" variable twice, the "d" variable twice, 2 quoted strings and a numeric literal.

Since "date" and "d" as variables have not been initialized, they are treated as either the empty string or as the number zero, depending on the context. Because you use `-` between "date" and "d", you are putting them into a numeric context.

Also note that:

- awk string contatenation is to simply put 2 strings side-by-side: there is no explicit operator
- the `$` symbol can be described as a "field-value dereferencing" operator: the word on the right-hand side of `$` is the field number to use.
- in the BEGIN block, awk has not yet processed any records, so any `$x` will become the empty string

awk essentially sees this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print date -d $(date -d "20181222" "+%Y%m%d") + 30}'
awk 'BEGIN { print (0 - 0) $((0 - 0) "20181222" "+%Y%m%d") + 30}'  # variable values
awk 'BEGIN { print 0 $(0 "20181222" "+%Y%m%d") + 30}'              # arithmetic
awk 'BEGIN { print 0 $("020181222+%Y%m%d") + 30}'                  # string concat
awk 'BEGIN { print 0 $(20181222) + 30}'                            # field is a number
awk 'BEGIN { print 0 "" + 30}'                                     # field value
awk 'BEGIN { print 0 (0 + 30)}'                                    # numeric context
awk 'BEGIN { print 0 30}'                                          # arithmetic
awk 'BEGIN { print "030"}'                                         # string concat
```

---

You can do date arithmetic natively in GNU awk: see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

```
gawk -v date=20181222 -v days=30 'BEGIN {
  datespec = substr(date, 1, 4) " " substr(date, 5, 2) " " (substr(date, 7, 2) + days) " 0 0 0"
  time = mktime(datespec)
  print strftime("%Y%m%d", time)
}'
```

```
20190121
```

Fortunately, GNU awk's datetime library recognises "December 52nd, 2018" as "January 21st, 2019"

---

If you don't have GNU awk and can't install it, perl should suffice:

```
perl -sE '
    use Time::Piece;
    use Time::Seconds;
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%Y%m%d");
    $t += $days * ONE_DAY;
    say $t->ymd("");          # or, say $t->strftime("%Y%m%d")
' -- -date=20181222 -days=30
```

Comment: I don't think the first 0 is quoted at this point. `print "0" $("020181222+%Y%m%d") + 30}`.  It should read `0 ("" + 30)` then `0 30`

Comment: Thank you @glenn. It will be useful.

Comment: very nice breakdown!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need `awk` for this one, seems like you have GNU `date`, if yes then try following once.

```
date '+%Y%m%d' -d "20181222+30 days"
20190121
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use awk. This way does not work if there is another way to add up days using awk without "date" it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a command within `awk`

```
$ awk -v d=30 'BEGIN{cmd="date -d \"20181222+" d "days\" +\"%Y%m%d\""; 
                     cmd | getline date; print "date:" date}'

date:20190121
```

Comment: `cmd | getline date` -> `date = ((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "-1"); close(cmd)` for robustness, etc.